# Unable to find file which sets Django installation's location

Tags: django

I have a Django installation at /home/masi/mySite.

**How can you set that the files at the folder */home/masi/public_html/mySite* uses the Django installation?**

Comment: We may need a bit more help here, Masi. Are you asking how to get Apache or some other webserver to use the Django install when running your app? Or are you talking about the local django dev server?

Comment: @Jarret: I run Django on my server at Djangohosting.ch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<location "/">

    SetHandler python-program

    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython

    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE myproject.settings

    PythonPath "['/home/masi/public_html'] + sys.path"

</location>
```

In http.conf the python path will specify the location of the django project.

Also http://www.djangoproject.com/ provides great documentation.

Comment: `mod_python` is deprecated, you should promote other way to deploy django, see : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Answer (score -1):

you can use .htaccess files too

```
SetHandler python-program 
PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython 
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE yourproject.settings 
PythonDebug On 

PythonPath "['/your/project/path'] + sys.path"
```

Comment: `mod_python` is deprecated, you should use `mod_wsgi` with apache, see : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/